# Как получить значки пользователя discord

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Как получить эти значки из профиля пользователя дискорда? Если я например хочу их вывести в виде текста в какой-нибудь `Embed`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно загрузить свои эмодзи и просто подставлять

```
@commands.command()
async def user(self, ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    hypesquad_class = str(member.public_flags.all()).replace('[<UserFlags.', '').replace('>]', '').replace('_',' ').replace(':', '').title()
    hypesquad_class = ''.join([i for i in hypesquad_class if not i.isdigit()])
    return await ctx.reply(embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{str(member)} User's Badges", description=f"{hypesquad_class}", color=0xff0000), mention_author=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

В discord.py нет значка Nitro и Boost.

Значки: [Тык](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.PublicUserFlags)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос